# Proper way to disable jQuery UI dragging on some members of a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have a class to which jQuery UI draggable is applied too.
I want some classes in that are also members of that parent class to not be draggable.

I've tried:

```
$('.class:not(.class1, .class2, .class3').draggable({
    //
});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpJ8/2/
also

```
$('.class').not('.class1, .class2, .class3').draggable({
    //
});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpJ8/3/
also

```
$('.class').not('.class1').not('.class2').not('.class3').draggable({
    //
});
```

Same JS Fiddle as above
and

```
$('.class').draggable({
    start: function(){
        if($(this).is('.class1')) return false;
        if($(this).is('.class2')) return false;
        if($(this).is('.class3')) return false;
    }
});
```

This blocks everything: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpJ8/4/

None of these seem to work.

Is there a way in CSS or JS / jQuery that I can properly disable draggable? Why I want to is so that elements of these smaller classes' text can be highlightable and selectable so that the contextual right-menu can be triggered and the user can copy or anything in the menu.

Comment: I'm surprised those things don't work. Can you create a small jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @dgvid Dysfunction jsfiddles added to question under code

Comment: Just FYI: In your jsfiddle examples, none of the divs have class "focused" when you call the draggable method. Adding the "focused" class later does not automatically update the draggable state of the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `"destroy"` as a parameter for draggable, so your code will look like

```
$('.class').draggable();
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').draggable("destroy");
```

Comment: `'destroy' nor "destroy" is working. They are still dragging.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder what could be causing that. Maybe you need to do something like this `$('.class').draggable(function(){
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').draggable("destroy");
});`

Comment: It was probably the order the functions were getting called it was messing things up. This ensures that the draggable only gets destroyed after it is added I guess.